# Unity Gradle Error When Android Project Exported To Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

```
This is my code.

// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    implementation project(':unityLibrary')
    }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        applicationId 'com.DefaultCompany.NawabiRunner'
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
        versionCode 1
        versionName '0.1'
    }


    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip '*/armeabi-v7a/*.so'
    }

    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        density {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        abi {
            enableSplit = true
        }
    }
    androidResources {
        ignoreAssetsPattern '!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~'
        noCompress '[\'.ress\', \'.resource\', \'.obb\'] + unityStreamingAssets.tokenize(\', \')'
    }
}



and this is my Error : 


Build file 'F:\rrr\launcher\build.gradle' line: 3

A problem occurred evaluating project ':launcher'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: The option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated.
     It was removed in version 7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
     Please remove it from `gradle.properties`.

* Try:
Run with --stack trace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I want to run an unity3D project in Android Studio and for that, I fetched my project from Unity and tried to run it by android Studio. But it is giving me the above errors.

I have tried to update the Gradle, and actually, I upgraded the Gradle, but it didn't help.
I am having a headache for 2 hours due to this error but this error is not leaving me. Kindly help me in removing this error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove line android.enableR8 from gradle.properties file in android studio. This is because it is deprecated.